# How count results from query

Tags: mysql, join, count

How to count results from this query using `COUNT` keyword?

`SELECT COUNT (*)` returns wrong result.

```
SELECT files.* FROM files
LEFT JOIN tags_files ON tags_files.id_file = files.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_files.id
WHERE tags.name LIKE '%search%' OR files.name LIKE '%search%'
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Try adding more explanation to your question.

Comment: I have pagination and first i must count results to next insert in main query limits page and this query work, but before i must count this results.

Comment: Do you want to count the records returned by the query above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query if you want to count the results:

```
SELECT COUNT( files.id ) AS total_num FROM files
LEFT JOIN tags_files ON tags_files.id_file = files.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_files.id
WHERE tags.name LIKE '%search%' OR files.name LIKE '%search%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowCount or num_rows depends on what you use, so it will only counts the rows that your query returns

example:

```html
<?php 
    //For PDO
    $sel = $dbh->prepare("SELECT files.* FROM files LEFT JOIN tags_files ON   tags_files.id_file = files.id LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_files.id WHERE tags.name LIKE '%search%' OR files.name LIKE '%search%'");
    $sel->execute();
    $count = $sel->rowCount();
  
    //For mysqli
    $sel = "SELECT files.* FROM files LEFT JOIN tags_files ON   tags_files.id_file = files.id LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_files.id WHERE tags.name LIKE '%search%' OR files.name LIKE '%search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sel);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```